Is it possible to adjust elevation of 3D data in CesiumJS?
I am new to CesiumJS, but have the following code which focuses on Southern San Francisco and I have also drawn a red rectangle on top of the 3D World Terrain
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <!-- Include the CesiumJS JavaScript and CSS files -->
  <script src="https://cesium.com/downloads/cesiumjs/releases/1.119/Build/Cesium/Cesium.js"></script>
  <link href="https://cesium.com/downloads/cesiumjs/releases/1.119/Build/Cesium/Widgets/widgets.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
  <div id="cesiumContainer"></div>
  <script type="module">
    // Your access token can be found at: https://ion.cesium.com/tokens.
    // This is the default access token from your ion account

    Cesium.Ion.defaultAccessToken = 'eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJqdGkiOiI4MjViMDdiOC02OTBlLTQyYjgtOTcyYy02YTYzNjczNDgxN2QiLCJpZCI6MjI2NDQ1LCJpYXQiOjE3MjAxMDMzNjV9.tSVOLKfyeiR0kn1e0G13O2PA6E8dLU3J6531muHF16g';

    // Initialize the Cesium Viewer in the HTML element with the `cesiumContainer` ID.
    const viewer = new Cesium.Viewer('cesiumContainer', {
      terrain: Cesium.Terrain.fromWorldTerrain(),
    });    

    // Fly the camera to San Francisco at the given longitude, latitude, and height.
    viewer.camera.flyTo({
      destination: Cesium.Cartesian3.fromDegrees(-122.4175, 37.655, 400),
      orientation: {
        heading: Cesium.Math.toRadians(0.0),
        pitch: Cesium.Math.toRadians(-15.0),
      }
    });
    const geoJsonMountainPolygon = {
      type: "Feature",
      properties: {},
      geometry: {
        type: "Polygon",
        coordinates: [[
          [-122.5, 37.6],
          [-122.4, 37.6],
          [-122.4, 37.7],
          [-122.5, 37.7],
          [-122.5, 37.6]
        ]]
      }
    };

    const mountainPolygonEntity = viewer.entities.add({
      polygon: {
        hierarchy: Cesium.Cartesian3.fromDegreesArray([
          -122.5, 37.6,
          -122.4, 37.6,
          -122.4, 37.7,
          -122.5, 37.7,
          -122.5, 37.6
        ]),
        material: Cesium.Color.RED.withAlpha(0.5),
        outline: true,
        outlineColor: Cesium.Color.BLACK
      }
    });
    
    
  </script>
 </div>
</body>
</html>

enter image description here
However, what I am wondering is - does CesiumJS have the capability to manipulate the elevation of the terrain? E.g. exaggerate it further, flatten it, etc?
I have been trying to write code to write a custom tile provider where the terrain is flattened if the tiles fall within the red rectangle that I've drawn
customTerrainProvider.requestTileGeometry = function(x, y, level, request) {
  const rectangle = Cesium.EllipsoidTilingScheme.tileXYToRectangle(x, y, level);
  const cartographicPosition = Cesium.Rectangle.center(rectangle);
  const isInMountainPolygon = Cesium.Cartesian3.fromDegrees(cartographicPosition.longitude, cartographicPosition.latitude);
  
  if (Cesium.PolygonPipeline.insidePolygon(isInMountainPolygon, geoJsonMountainPolygon.geometry.coordinates[0])) {
    return Cesium.EllipsoidTerrainProvider.prototype.getLevelMaximumGeometricError(level);
  } else {
    // Call the original method to get the default terrain data
    return Cesium.EllipsoidTerrainProvider.prototype.requestTileGeometry.call(this, x, y, level, request)
      .then(function(terrainData) {
        // Add custom terrain manipulation logic here
        terrainData.interpolateHeight = function (rectangle, longitude, latitude) {
          // Custom logic to flatten terrain to desired elevation
          return Cesium.Cartesian3.fromRadians(longitude, latitude, desiredElevation);
        };

        return terrainData;
      });
  }
};

But that is just resulting in Cesium pointing to the sky ...
I've noticed Cesium World Bathymetry has a slider which can exaggerate the bathymetry https://cesium.com/blog/2024/01/29/cesium-world-bathymetry-in-cesiumjs/ - is there any way I could implement something similar for the 3D World Terrain? Or this https://sandcastle.cesium.com/?src=3D%20Tiles%20Vertical%20Exaggeration.html ??

did you check this sample? https://sandcastle.cesium.com/gallery/Terrain%20Exaggeration.html
